# Redirect to custom domain from startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have asp .net core project with custom authentication domain. So, when i hit the login url at that time i want to redirect my custom domain.

for that, I have code for redirection, but it will not accept urn and realm. because I have one MVC project and in this, I set up all configuration related my custom auth domain in web.config file and it will redirect on custom auth from only one line code which is: `realm : "mycurentlocalhost" issuer : "authportalurl" in web.config`, So how to set up this code in asp .net core because the .net core has not web.config and if I redirect from startup then it will cause an error from my auth portal you are not subscriber because I don't know how to pass urn from asp .net core startup file.

I have tried with `contect.Response.Redirect("customportalurl")` in configure method startup file.

```
var url = "customdomainurl";

if (context.Request.Path.Value.IndexOf(url, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
{         
    context.Response.Redirect(url);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do with by adding middleware. In Startup.cs class there is one method `Configure`.You need to add below code

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    var request = context.Request;
                    var host = request.Host;
                    if (host.Host.Equals("customdomainurl", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(UriHelper.Encode(request.Scheme, newHost,
                            request.PathBase, request.Path, request.QueryString));
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                    return next();
                });
```

Comment: Hello

Its absolutely correct but i want to send "urn" with my "url" beacuse custom portal dont know curent request from where its coming so its not validate because its said that incoming request not subscriber for our portal, for that we need to pass "urn" like our localhost with custom portal "url".

Thanks